# My program won't stop executing the if statement yet the condition is not met

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, while-loop

It's supposed to be a multiplication table from 1 to 6 on the x axis and 1 to 5 on the y axis, so I have this if statement that is supposed to jump to the nezt line once the multiplication reaches 6 but it keeps on executing even though I reset the condition that is to be met within it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
int mult = 1;
int check = 0;
int res;
while(mult != 6){


        if (check <= 6){
            res = mult * check;
            printf("%d ",res);
            check ++;
        }
        if (check > 6 ){
            printf("\n ");
            check = 0;
        }

}}
```

Comment: `int check = 0;` declares a new variable. Try just `check = 0;`. Your loop will never end because `mult` is never changed.

Comment: Try to debug your code and check the value of `mul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement makes you execute or not a block.

For instance, in your code:

```
if (check <= 6){
    res = mult * check;
    printf("%d ",res);
    check ++;
}
if (check > 6 ){
    printf("\n ");
    int check = 0;
}
```

The first block will be executed when `check <= 6`, the second one will be executed with `check > 6`... but the condition in the `while` loop is `mult != 5`... and you are never modifying `mult`, so the condition is always true.

So, in addition to uZuMaKioBaRuTo's remark on your `check` variable, you also need to increment `mult`:

```
if (check > 6 ){
    printf("\n ");
    check = 0;
    mult++;
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo I understood my mistake thanks